# Exception starting filter [jfinal] in Ubuntu

Tags: java, jsp, ubuntu, tomcat

I am developing JSP web site without JSP Framework like Spring or Struts.
I used only Mybatis.
And I use Tomcat 8.0.53 & JDK 1.8.0_151 on Windows 10, Tomcat 8.0.53 & JDK 1.8.0_131 on Ubuntu 16.04.2.
My web site is working correctly in Windows, but it occurs error in Ubuntu like this.

```
07-Nov-2017 02:19:09.069 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [jfinal]
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.PoolBackedDataSourceBase.<init>(PoolBackedDataSourceBase.java:54)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.<init>(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:74)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:142)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:138)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:47)
at com.jfinal.plugin.c3p0.C3p0Plugin.start(C3p0Plugin.java:150)
at com.jfinal.core.Config.startPlugins(Config.java:107)
at com.jfinal.core.Config.configJFinal(Config.java:53)
at com.jfinal.core.JFinal.init(JFinal.java:63)
at com.jfinal.core.JFinalFilter.init(JFinalFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4591)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.find(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig.readVmConfig(MConfig.java:75)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.findLibraryMultiPropertiesConfig(C3P0Config.java:157)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.<clinit>(C3P0Config.java:143)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.mchange.v1.lang.Synchronizer$1.invoke(Synchronizer.java:58)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.cfg.BasicMultiPropertiesConfig.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.ConfigUtils.read(ConfigUtils.java:63)
at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig$CSManager.recreateFromKey(MConfig.java:153)
at com.mchange.v1.cachedstore.NoCleanupCachedStore.find(NoCleanupCachedStore.java:63)
... 35 more
```

I don't know why this error occurs.
I need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your libraries are out of sync. Make sure the versions of your jar files are compatible with each other.

Comment: Thanks. Then there are 150 jar files in my project. How can I check them? What files occur this exception?

Comment: The file that contains class `com.mchange.v2.cfg.ConfigUtils` seems to be out of sync with the file that contains class `com.mchange.v2.cfg.BasicMultiPropertiesConfig`, because that's where the `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown. Read the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @DmitriStepan Stepan, How did you fix?, I have a similar problem.